# Are passports still stamped at Eilat-Ovda airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, israel

At Ben Gurion airport, passports are not stamped, with foreigners being given entry and exit Slips.

What about Eilat-Ovda airport? Do they have the same system, or do they still use passport stamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find 2017 information but Ben Gurion started not stamping in 2013 and I found personal reports indicating Ovda was still doing it in 2015 and 2016.

https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/middle-east/israel/requesting-not-to-stamp-passport this is 2015:

> if you happen to arrive at Ovda airport near Eilat, they do stamp inward and outward as well :-(. My own experience.

https://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g293977-i1733-k9238137-Israel_travel_review_with_the_facts-Israel.html this is 2016

> In Ovda airport stamped passport and some security questions (where you stay, where you planning to go). Entering, each passenger receives a nice gift from Eilat (information and Dead Sea cream).

Also note this question and answer will become quickly completely and hopelessly outdated since civilian flights to Ovda will cease in less than a year once Ramon opens currently scheduled to early 2018.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that they no longer stamp passports, you get a separate slip of paper!

Comment: Is it an electronic entry slip like at Ben Gurion, or the old-style one with a manual stamp that's been issued in the past for those wanting to visit countries boycotting Israel?